# CASE WHEN with ASC/DESC in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this query to fetch articles. If `article sponsor status` is true, then it has priority to be seen at top.

```
SELECT article_id, article_name, article_image, article_url, 
article_feature_status, article_sponsor_status
FROM articles ORDER BY CASE WHEN article_sponsor_status = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END DESC
```

I got result as I want but I also want to get result as DESC from new to old. With this query starts from top to analyze but I would like to reverse it. The last "DESC" doesnt work I expected. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

**This worked**

```
SELECT article_id, article_name, article_image, article_url, article_feature_status, article_sponsor_status
FROM articles  ORDER BY CASE WHEN article_sponsor_status = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, article_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need a second key for the `ORDER BY`.  Your data doesn't have an obvious column that represents the date, but something like:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM articles
ORDER BY CASE WHEN article_sponsor_status = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC,
         <some date field> DESC
```

In MySQL you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM articles
ORDER BY (article_sponsor_status = 'true') DESC,
         <some date field> DESC
```

In a numeric context, MySQL treats booleans as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So a descending sort puts the matches before the non-matches.

Comment: Thanks the query that I updated in post worked successfully as you meant. At the end I used DESC for article_id!